# Differentiating the checkbox selection & row selection in dxDataGrid

Tags: devextreme

I implemented dxData grid with the following option.
 selection: {
    mode: 'multiple'
 }
And also have a different functionality for onRowClick & onSelectionChanged.

While the onRowClick event is getting fired , It fires the onSelectionChanged event also.

Can anyone suggest how to differntiate these two event?
I mean when the row click event is getting fired, it should not file the onSelectionChanged event. The onSelectionChanged event should fire while selecting the check boxes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior for the `dxDataGrid` widget.

To implement your scenario you can add a column with checkboxes manually:

```
{ 
     name: 'Selected',
     cellTemplate: function($cell, cellInfo) {
         var $checkBox = $("<div>").dxCheckBox({
             onValueChanged: function(args) {
                 // put selection changed handler here....
             }
            }).appendTo($cell);
        }
}
```

I've created a small sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/v2fswrvr/

Comment: In that example also it is not working because when we checking an checkbox row click event is getting fired.

Comment: Use [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/v2fswrvr/2/